# Canvas uses a lot of CPU

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, qtquick2

I am using `Canvas` in QML to draw rotating `Rectangle` with OpenGL. Here is the code:

```
//...
property variant points: []

onPointsChanged:{
    canvas.requestPaint();
}

//...

Canvas{
    //...

    onPaint:{
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

        ctx.clearRect(0,0, width, height);
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
        ctx.lineWidth = 3

        for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
            var p1 = convertPoint(points[i])
            if(i == 0){
                ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y)
                continue
            }

            ctx.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y)
        }
        ctx.stroke()
        ctx.restore()
    }

    function convertPoint(p){
        var x = p.x * width;
        var y = p.y * height;
        return Qt.point(x,y);
    }
}
```

There are 4 points counted in c++ code and sent to qml every 30ms. Problem is that this paint operation takes 50% of CPU usage when compile under MinGW and when compile under MSVC2010 operation takes 17% of CPU, which is still a lot. It is some bug or what is bad?

Comment: and if you compile with optimizations enabled?

Comment: Can u tell me how can I do it?

Comment: You can start from this: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/16833

Comment: How are you "sending" the points to QML?

I made your example runnable (no C++ for simplicity, ugly rotation), and it consumes around 10% CPU: http://pastebin.kde.org/pzgh1x1e1

Answer (score 5):

Consider using the [new scene graph classes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html) instead of `Canvas` if performance is critical. In particular, you'd be interested in the [QSGGeometryNode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsggeometrynode.html) class. If you prefer the simplicity of the `Canvas` API, you have to be aware of how it's best used. [This article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/) gives you some insight into that.

Edit: I've also found improvements on embedded hardware (specifically the Raspberry Pi) using the [QQuickPaintedItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qquickpainteditem.html) class in certain cases.