# Incrase WebView HTML5 Canvas in QT

Tags: html, performance, qt, canvas, webview

I'm porting a current HTML5 Canvas application to a QT wrapper. however its performance is quite low. This HTML5 canvas app runs at 60fps in Chrome and IE11, however it still at 10fps on QTWebView.

How can I increase the render speed of this existent HTML5 canvas application inside a QT project?
the question is about if there is any parameter to use some more fast renderer (like GPU)

Note. this project was created using the default qt creator wizard for HTML5 applications.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your code. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764674/qt-qml-canvas-use-a-lot-of-cpu/19766867#19766867) has a link to an article that offers some advice for using Canvas efficiently.

Comment: it is not about efficient canvas implementation. My app runs at 60fps in chrome and IE11, however it still at 10fps on QTWebView. the question is about if there is any parameter to use some more fast like a GPU