# How to integrate a custom GraphicsItem into a QML scene?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qgraphicsitem

Assume you have created the following custom `QGraphicsRectItem` in C++:

```
class MyCustomItem : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
  public:
    MyCustomItem(MyCustomItem* a_Parent = 0);
    virtual ~MyCustomItem();

    // specific methods

  private:
    // specific data
};
```

Assume also that you have defined in a QML script an `ApplicationWindow`:

```
// main.qml
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: myWindow
    title: qsTr("My Window")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
}
```

The simple task I would like to do is to display an instance of `MyCustomItem` in that `ApplicationWindow`. I wanted to do the following:

```
// part of main.cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    MyCustomItem* myItem;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("MyCustomItem", myItem);

    return app.exec();
}
```

But of course this doesn't work, because `MyCustomItem` is neither a `QObject` nor a `QVariant`. I don't want my item to be anything else than a `QGraphicsRectItem`. Isn't that possible to display that graphics item? That should be simple as hell, shouldn't it? Is there a way with `QDeclarativeItem` or something? I can't find how to solve this problem, that's very frustrating. Would I implement my application with "normal" Qt, the problem would already be solved, because in this case you have a scene, and the scene has a member method `addItem()` and I don't need to do complicated stuff to add my custom graphics item to my scene. Do I have to wrap this item in a `QDeclarativeItem` or a `QObject` in order to get the thing done? That would be so awful, in my opinion. Aren't there better options?

### EDIT

Can that be that `QGraphicsRectItem` is not the right class to inherit from and that something like `QQuickPaintedItem` (as suggested in the comments) would be more appropriate?

Comment: you need to write a QML Extensions  Item, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-tutorials-extending-qml-example.html

Comment: In `QML` your custom item must be descendent of `QQuickitem` or `QQuickPaintedItem` if you want base your painting ot QPainter. `QGraphicsItem` works in `QGraphicsScene` which isn't present in QML. But `QQuickitem` and `QGraphicsItem` are similar and you easy can adopt it to use in `QML` scene.

Comment: I have read lines of text of the kind "must be descendent of QQuickitem or QQuickPaintedItem if you want your painting to be based on QPainter". What are the other options we have in QML, if I don't want to use QPainter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't speak for Qt 4, but in Qt 5, you have several options for custom drawing:

#### [`QQuickPaintedItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickpainteditem.html)

A QPainter-based `QQuickItem`. This sounds the closest to what you want. A snippet from the documentation of [one of the examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-customitems-painteditem-example.html):

```
void TextBalloon::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    QBrush brush(QColor("#007430"));

    painter->setBrush(brush);
    painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    painter->drawRoundedRect(0, 0, boundingRect().width(), boundingRect().height() - 10, 10, 10);

    if (rightAligned)
    {
        const QPointF points[3] = {
            QPointF(boundingRect().width() - 10.0, boundingRect().height() - 10.0),
            QPointF(boundingRect().width() - 20.0, boundingRect().height()),
            QPointF(boundingRect().width() - 30.0, boundingRect().height() - 10.0),
        };
        painter->drawConvexPolygon(points, 3);
    }
    else
    {
        const QPointF points[3] = {
            QPointF(10.0, boundingRect().height() - 10.0),
            QPointF(20.0, boundingRect().height()),
            QPointF(30.0, boundingRect().height() - 10.0),
        };
        painter->drawConvexPolygon(points, 3);
    }
}
```

#### [`Canvas`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html)

JavaScript-based drawing QML type with an [HTML5-like](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html#tips-for-porting-existing-html5-canvas-applications) API. A snippet from [one of the examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-canvas-squircle-squircle-qml.html):

```
Canvas {
    id: canvas
    width: 320
    height: 250
    antialiasing: true

    property color strokeStyle: Qt.darker(fillStyle, 1.2)
    property color fillStyle: "#6400aa"

    property int lineWidth: 2
    property int nSize: nCtrl.value
    property real radius: rCtrl.value
    property bool fill: true
    property bool stroke: false
    property real px: width/2
    property real py: height/2 + 10
    property real alpha: 1.0

    onRadiusChanged: requestPaint();
    onLineWidthChanged: requestPaint();
    onNSizeChanged: requestPaint();
    onFillChanged: requestPaint();
    onStrokeChanged: requestPaint();

    onPaint: squcirle();

    function squcirle() {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var N = canvas.nSize;
        var R = canvas.radius;

        N=Math.abs(N);
        var M=N;
        if (N>100) M=100;
        if (N<0.00000000001) M=0.00000000001;

        ctx.save();
        ctx.globalAlpha =canvas.alpha;
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        ctx.strokeStyle = canvas.strokeStyle;
        ctx.fillStyle = canvas.fillStyle;
        ctx.lineWidth = canvas.lineWidth;

        ctx.beginPath();
        var i = 0, x, y;
        for (i=0; i<(2*R+1); i++){
            x = Math.round(i-R) + canvas.px;
            y = Math.round(Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.pow(R,M)-Math.pow(Math.abs(i-R),M)),1/M)) + canvas.py;

            if (i == 0)
                ctx.moveTo(x, y);
            else
                ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        }

        for (i=(2*R); i<(4*R+1); i++){
            x =Math.round(3*R-i)+canvas.px;
            y = Math.round(-Math.pow(Math.abs(Math.pow(R,M)-Math.pow(Math.abs(3*R-i),M)),1/M)) + canvas.py;
            ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        }
        ctx.closePath();
        if (canvas.stroke) {
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        if (canvas.fill) {
            ctx.fill();
        }
        ctx.restore();
    }
}
```

#### [`QSGGeometryNode`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsggeometrynode.html)

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19766867/904422) answer, you could take advantage of the [Qt Quick Scene Graph](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html). A snippet from [one of the examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-customgeometry-example.html):

```
QSGNode *BezierCurve::updatePaintNode(QSGNode *oldNode, UpdatePaintNodeData *)
{
    QSGGeometryNode *node = 0;
    QSGGeometry *geometry = 0;

    if (!oldNode) {
        node = new QSGGeometryNode;
        geometry = new QSGGeometry(QSGGeometry::defaultAttributes_Point2D(), m_segmentCount);
        geometry->setLineWidth(2);
        geometry->setDrawingMode(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        node->setGeometry(geometry);
        node->setFlag(QSGNode::OwnsGeometry);
        QSGFlatColorMaterial *material = new QSGFlatColorMaterial;
        material->setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0));
        node->setMaterial(material);
        node->setFlag(QSGNode::OwnsMaterial);
    } else {
        node = static_cast<QSGGeometryNode *>(oldNode);
        geometry = node->geometry();
        geometry->allocate(m_segmentCount);
    }

    QRectF bounds = boundingRect();
    QSGGeometry::Point2D *vertices = geometry->vertexDataAsPoint2D();
    for (int i = 0; i < m_segmentCount; ++i) {
        qreal t = i / qreal(m_segmentCount - 1);
        qreal invt = 1 - t;

        QPointF pos = invt * invt * invt * m_p1
                    + 3 * invt * invt * t * m_p2
                    + 3 * invt * t * t * m_p3
                    + t * t * t * m_p4;

        float x = bounds.x() + pos.x() * bounds.width();
        float y = bounds.y() + pos.y() * bounds.height();

        vertices[i].set(x, y);
    }
    node->markDirty(QSGNode::DirtyGeometry);

    return node;
}
```

#### [`QQuickWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwidget.html)

If you really want to use `QGraphicsItem` subclasses, you could go the opposite direction, and have a widget-based app that contains certain "Qt Quick Widgets", though this is not optimal (see [Qt Weekly #16: QQuickWidget](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/07/02/qt-weekly-16-qquickwidget/) for more information).