# Paint a Path curve in QML with a shadow box

Tags: c++, qt, path, qml, shapes

I need to create a line like the image below. Does anyone have any suggestions?

[target image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiiGO.png)

In addition to the mentioned image, it is necessary to select the line with the mouse, which can be done with TapHandler.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635753/how-to-integrate-a-custom-graphicsitem-into-a-qml-scene/31650722#31650722

Comment: People responded, so I'll just leave you with the option of reviewing the nice repo that created your target image in QML + C++: https://github.com/SC-One/QuickQanava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT/REWRITE]

You can consider using `Shape, ShapePath` for drawing the shadow and the line and you can consider using `Image` to draw and rotate an SVG arrow head:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Shapes
Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "black" }
    ListModel {
        id: line
        Component.onCompleted: {
            for (let pt of [
                { ix: 100, iy: 140 },
                { ix: 150, iy: 160 },
                { ix: 250, iy: 180 },
                { ix: 400, iy: 200 }
            ] )
            append( pt );
        }
    }
    Repeater {
        model: line.count > 1 ? line.count - 1 : 0
        Shape {
            ShapePath {
                startX: line.get(index).ix
                startY: line.get(index).iy
                strokeColor: "#444"
                strokeWidth: 20
                capStyle: ShapePath.RoundCap
                PathLine {
                    x: line.get(index + 1).ix
                    y: line.get(index + 1).iy
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Repeater {
        model: line.count > 1 ? line.count - 1 : 0
        Shape {
            ShapePath {
                startX: line.get(index).ix
                startY: line.get(index).iy
                strokeColor: "white"
                strokeWidth: 3
                capStyle: ShapePath.RoundCap
                PathLine {
                    x: line.get(index + 1).ix
                    y: line.get(index + 1).iy
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Image {
        x: line.get(line.count - 1).ix - width / 2
        y: line.get(line.count - 1).iy - height / 2
        source: "arrow-head.svg"
        cache: false
        transformOrigin: Item.Center
        rotation: Math.atan2(
        line.get(line.count - 1).iy - line.get(line.count - 2).iy,
        line.get(line.count - 1).ix - line.get(line.count - 2).ix
        ) * 180 / Math.PI
    }
    Repeater {
        model: line
        Rectangle {
            x: ix - width / 2
            y: iy - height / 2
            width: 20
            height: 20
            color: "transparent"
            border.color: dragArea.containsMouse || dragArea.drag.active ? "red" : "transparent"
            Drag.active: dragArea.drag.active
            Drag.hotSpot.x: 10
            Drag.hotSpot.y: 10
            onXChanged: Qt.callLater(update)
            onYChanged: Qt.callLater(update)
            MouseArea {
                id: dragArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                drag.target: parent
hoverEnabled: true
            }
            function update() {
                line.setProperty(index, "ix", x + width / 2);
                line.setProperty(index, "iy", y + height / 2);
            }
        }
    }
}

// arrow-head.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path fill="white" d="M 16 8 L 0 12 L 0 4 z"/> 
</svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Hi Stephen,
 My target line is dynamic, my problem is to draw a shadow box on the line while selected. Can use svg when the line has a dynamic start and end points?

Comment: @MohsenAbdolahzadehKondori I rewrote the answer. Does this work for you?

Comment: Quen,  Must be used another MouseArea on the Shape. when line shape is hovered, the shadow shape must be visible.

Comment: @MohsenAbdolahzadehKondori do you believe you have satisfactorily described the problem clearly?

Comment: My problem is to draw a curve that can be selected with the mouse and create a shadow line around it by selecting it (like the code you wrote).

Comment: Hi  Stephen, How can I select this line? @StephenQuen